# does every procedure call create a recursive session in oracle

Tags: oracle10g

I'm trying to solve a case of constant ora--00018 "maximum open sessions exceeded"  crashes even though sessions parameter  in set to 1500, during those crushes number of v)session entries is sometimes  50 % off  v$ resource_limit. current_utilization value of sessions parameter. So we suspect there  are a lot of recursive sessions being made and that quickly  brings A DB Server down. I know that triggers can cause a lot off recursive sessions . Does every procedure call create the same effect or are any specific kind of procedure that generate it. I tried to test by checking the current_utilization value before  and after I ran a simple procedure and didn't see the difference. Maybe because my test procedure is too simple and too fast to notice.  I've read this article http://tech.e2sn.com/oracle/oracle-internals-and-architecture/recursive-sessions-and-ora-00018-maximum-number-of-sessions-exceeded but it's not clear to me  if  every procedure is run on a different session . I'm using oracle 10g

Comment: Are you closing connections?

Comment: yes we do close them forcibly after 10min

Comment: But are the client applications closing the sessions or are they just leaving them there to hang so that you have to forcibly close them? If they create a new connection for every query and don't close the connections then that is your problem (or two problems, not closing connections and not re-using connections).

Comment: @MT0 yes, you were right, It turned out to be one of the junior devs, that decided to be economical, and save one of code by using code like this try (PreparedStatement st_stage_CF = Global.getConnection().prepareStatement ("  sql  query "))

{

...

}

Comment: Doing so prevented  connection from being closed even though it technically was inside try() . Because this code and 3 other similar lines  was  at very popular module inside our system (at one point 500 concurrent users ) but because of  this error we  constantly  ran out of sessions()